# Motivating yourself to be back in photography

Tags: motivation

I am a hobbyist photographer, i had a d90, but it got stolen and later found out my relatives stole it and ever since my motivation broke down. Then i got myself a new upgraded model just thinking it will reengage me into photography again. I carry my camera all the time my bag and yet, never i take it out. I pass so many places in car to stop by and get shots, but thinking that my photography sucks and i don't get much likes or reviews on fb or website makes it cherry on top, hence me becoming effortless. 
Even i got studio lights but, my motivation is gone. what should i do?

Comment: If photography is a hobby for you and you're not motivated or aren't enjoying it, then don't.

Comment: @Nofel: hey man. I completely understand this, and I even know the entire thought flow behind this. Losing valuable things in life, especially things being stolen, makes the person feel betrayed in that area and withdraws himself from that and related things. You should keep photographing! I made 5000 bad shots to have one okay. And then so many more to have some good ones. But do not depend on likes, external opinions, as then you have it all wrong, for a hobby photographer! You should make photos because you WANT TO SAY SOMETHING! :-)

Comment: So sit down one day, and just think about it. What should your message be? What emotion do you want to show? What colors? If you have no clue, look up pictures on the internet and find ones you would like to copy. Yeah! If you cannot yet be creative, try to create the same shots you find aesthetic, working, pleasing for the eyes. And improve your skills. You will not be able to make good photos BEFORE you want to say something. It can be as silly as: "This is a dog". Or better: "This is a happy dog". Or "This is a happy dog having fun in the field". Etc. And just say it with your photos.

Comment: Motivation is something you create for yourself. You should not be dependent upon others creating this for yourself, because all this is is an internal thing. Photography is looking, observing, composing, and creating a message. You can do it very low level, like those Instagram craps, or high level, like some super pro photographers. But it is fun, game, really enjoyable. I myself do the following: I go on the street and ask random strangers to pose me for photos. I do not recommend this to you, because the rejection hurts a lot and the success rate is low. But I learnt so much from

Comment: interacting with strangers, now I can take a girl on the street and make superb photos! Also, you have studio lights! Man! High five! I would love to have studio lights! :-) And you can learn how to use them! Instantly a super interesting game! There are zillion books about flash photography, posing, models, lighting, low-key, high-key, then playing with color, color correction, and the post-processing... It is just: if you have studio lights, you have found Kriptonite! I freakin have to go to a super busy studio and suffer there, not cheap at all! :-) :-)

Comment: If you cannot find anything to photograph, photograph an animal. :-) If you cannot do that, photograph a still object with studio lighting. There are so many ways to light it... And if you cannot do that, make a photo of yourself. Then make a photo of yourself smiling. :-) Then in different poses. :-) There is a GENIUS in everyone art-wisely. And you can create great things. Do not depend on likes and positive feedback though. If you do not get those, you have not yet found your audience. Find your audience! Just keep making photos and make yourself known. :-) Good luck!